# Unable to run spring boot application with thymeleaf

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, thymeleaf

My main application class :

```
package com.sopra.springBoot;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args){
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
}
```

My controller :

```
    package com.sopra.springBoot;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String viewHome() {
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

My welcome.html file : which is located at */resources/templates/*

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3"
    xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
<body>First Spring Boot application

</body>

</html>
```

My pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.sopra.springBoot</groupId>
  <artifactId>sopra.springBoot</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> 
</parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Package as an executable jar/war -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I tried everything available on internet but still unable to locate templates folder and getting this error and *Whitelabel Error Page* on browser :

```
2018-01-23 16:08:38.878  WARN 2904 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.t.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration     : Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates or check your Thymeleaf configuration)
```

Please check where am i doing mistake. Still not able to display welcome.html.
Any idea regarding **ThymeleafAutoconfiguration** ?

Comment: Have you double checked if `welcome.html` file is located in `src/main/resources/templates`?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is 3 years later after the first answer. But @xingbin answer really helped me a lot.

Running the project through `mvn clean` and `mvn spring-boot:run` sure works.

But adding the code above to the classpath in application.properties didnt work to me. So I figured it out, I just need to remove the

> Asterisk * in `spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath*:/templates/`

Here is my code :

```
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML5
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
spring.thymeleaf.content-type=text/html
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine on my computer. I think this is because your [IDE can not resolve your classpath.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-template-engines)

> IntelliJ IDEA orders the classpath differently depending on how you
>   run your application. Running your application in the IDE via its main
>   method will result in a different ordering to when you run your
>   application using Maven or Gradle or from its packaged jar. This can
>   cause Spring Boot to fail to find the templates on the classpath. If
>   you’re affected by this problem you can reorder the classpath in the
>   IDE to place the module’s classes and resources first. Alternatively,
>   you can configure the template prefix to search every templates
>   directory on the classpath: classpath*:/templates/.

This can be solved by

- adding the resources folder to the class path, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25162773/how-do-i-add-a-directory-to-the-eclipse-classpath), then creating a file with name application.properties under folder resources, put below config in it to include all class paths:

  ```
  spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath*:/templates/
  spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
  spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
  spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
  spring.thymeleaf.content-type=text/html
  spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML5
  ```

Or

- running the project by executing `mvn clean` and `mvn spring-boot:run`.

Comment: any idea about eclipse oxygen ? I mean how to set classpath in that

Comment: @R.Sehdev try this https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-set-the-classpath-in-eclipse , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25162773/how-do-i-add-a-directory-to-the-eclipse-classpath

Comment: This deserves to be the accepted answer, it was the cause of the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

By default Spring Boot looking for thymeleaf in resources/templates folder. 
Just add templates folder to your resource and put you html files in templates

[image].

Comment: did it but still not picking path. I think something else is missing