# How to create subfolders with a build path in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot

I want to create two main folders under src folder. When i try this it creates in normal way as seen in image.

[image]

How can i create folders in this way.

[image]

```
src/main/java
src/main/resource
```

I have tried searching google and other websites. Nothing seems working. Also the option when you press `ctlr+F10` doesn't seem to solve my problem.

Comment: In your screen you have exactly that. Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: As you can see in image. It create subfolders under src and then main. I have seen some projects where it is been created as src/main/java. How can i do the same thing in my project.

Comment: You literally want a directory named `src/main/java`? Thats not possible.

Comment: Check my latest edited post

Comment: The second screen has the same directories, it just shows them differently.

Comment: They both are the same thing, src/main/java means you have a src folder and under that main folder and under that, java.

Comment: I know both are same thing. But I want to know how can I create in the desired way?

Comment: This is not possible as the forward dash is not accepted as part of a folder or file name in neither Win nor Linux (tested on Ubuntu). This is probably because it is a path delimiter and therefore reserved for that use.

Comment: This is just the way the view is presenting the folders, nothing to do with actual names of the folders. Is this Package Explorer, Project Explorer or something else?

Comment: The right terminology is "how to create a classpath folder in Eclipse" rather than a forward slash. This has nothing to do with [tag:spring-boot] and it has been asked on Stack Overflow already as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25162773/how-do-i-add-a-directory-to-the-eclipse-classpath.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add a directory to the eclipse classpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25162773/how-do-i-add-a-directory-to-the-eclipse-classpath)

Comment: Create a new project as a "Maven Project" (not as a "Java project"), then Eclipse will create this directory structure with /src/main/java and /src/main/resource

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> main>Folder --Right click--Build Path and select

use as a source folder

[image]

Comment: Thank You so much